# Pausing a loop in python

Tags: python, loops, pyqt, pyside

I have a loop that creates windows using PySide depending on the number the user enters 
each window will have some calls for other functions.
I would like the second window opens after all the commands belongs to the first window is done.
So, Is there a way in Python to tell the loop to stop until a certain flag is True for example

Here's what I'm doing

```
for i in range(values):
    self.CreatWindow()      # the function that creates the window



def CreatWindow(self):
    window = QtGui.QMainWindow(self)
    window.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
    combo = QtGui.QComboBox(window)
    combo.addItem(" ")
    combo.addItem("60")
    combo.addItem("45")
    combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)  

    btn = QtGui.QPushButton('OK', window)
    btn.clicked.connect(self.ComputeVec)
    window.show()

def onActivated(self, text):
    angle = int(text)

def ComputeVec(self):
    window.close()
    getVecValue(angle)
```

Now in that function the window have some calls to other functions, and I want to set the flag to True in the last function `getVecValue` which will do some computations and store the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having a different loop to open new windows you could call CreatWindow in ComputeVec
and use a global variable count to maintain count of windows created before.

```
count = 0
def ComputeVec(self):
    window.close()
    getVecValue(angle)
    global count
    count += 1
    if count in range(values) : 
        self.CreatWindow()
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop does already behave like this, since the function call `self.CreateWindow` waits for the return value of the called function.

You can return an appropriate value from `self.CreateWindow` for example `return True` and do this:

```
for i in range(values):
    success = self.CreateWindow()
    if success:
        continue
```

Anyway, if there is no return value in `self.CreateWindow`, the statement `self.CreateWindow()` is still evaluated and results to `None`. The loop is not finished until this result is achieved.

Comment: so I add some print statements to test if it is working 
what I added is a print statement after `success = self.CreateWindow()` and when running the script it creates all the windows and print before finishing the work on the first window